# Angular 10: how to close the preloader?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a preloader that should close as soon as I receive the message

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloaderService } from 'src/app/services/preloader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private preloaderService: PreloaderService) {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.preloaderService.showPreloader();
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {      
          console.log(event);      
  });
  
  }   
}
```

The preloader is closed using the function

```
this.preloaderService.hidePreloader();
```

my PreloaderService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PreloaderService {
    private isPreloaderVisibleSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    private preloaderProgressSubject: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);

    isPreloaderVisible: Observable<boolean> = this.isPreloaderVisibleSubject.asObservable();
    preloaderProgress: Observable<number> = this.preloaderProgressSubject.asObservable();

    constructor() {}

    updatePreloaderProgress(value: number) {
        this.preloaderProgressSubject.next(value);
    }

    showPreloader() {
        this.isPreloaderVisibleSubject.next(true);
    }

    hidePreloader() {
        this.isPreloaderVisibleSubject.next(false);
    }
}
```

But i don't understand in any way how to combine message and preloader

Comment: It's really not clear what your asking but I think you just want to add `this.preloaderService.hidePreloader();` to where you have `console.log(event);`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. I am sure this will solved your issue.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  var self = this;
  this.preloaderService.showPreloader();
  window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    self.preloaderService.hidePreloader();
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your event means it is load, then put it like that:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.preloaderService.showPreloader();
  window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    this.preloaderService.hidePreloader();
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Property 'preloaderService' does not exist on type 'Window'.
    
    16           this.preloaderService.hidePreloader();
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: I don't know what is ```preloaderService```.
I also can't see your error - it is hard to help you

Comment: use ```this.preloaderService```

Comment: If this is error from your service, maybe your library have an error?

Comment: I added preloaderService

Comment: ERROR in src/app/components/home/home.component.ts:16:16 - error TS2339: Property 'preloaderService' does not exist on type 'Window'.
    
    16           this.preloaderService.hidePreloader();
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~